# How to access variable inside of each using Handlebars and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to access my `author` variable inside of the each of `project.entities`... anyone know why I can't just do `{{author}}` and what I should do to achieve this?

**View**

```
        self.$el.html(self.template({
            project: this.model.attributes,
            author: this.model.get('authors')
        }));
```

**Template**

```
     <p class="author">by: {{author.full_name}}</p>
     <!-- author is available here -->
     {{#each project.entities}}
        <div class="audio">
            <div class="title-wave">
                <p class="title">{{this.title}}</p>
                <p class="author">by: {{author.full_name}}</p>
                <!-- author is not available inside of project each loop-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What does `this.model.get('authors')` return?

Comment: author object `{id:1, full_name: 'John Smith', dob:'12/12/2012'}`

Comment: What version of Handlebars are you including on the client side? I wonder if your precompiler and runtime library are using two different versions.

Answer (score 0):

### You're not accessing the right context

To access `author` you have to back out one conext level from the `project` each loop using `../`.

This behavior differs from Mustache behavior, where if there is no key in the current context, the parent contexts will be checked recursively.

Unfortunately, the [Handlebars documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) implies, but does not make clear this distinction.

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());
$("#rendered").html(template(
    {
        "project": {
            "entities": [
                {
                 "title": "Entity Title"
                }
            ]
        },
        "author": {
            "id"       : 1,
            "full_name": "John Smith",
            "dob"      : "12/12/2012"
        }
    }
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p class="author">by: {{author.full_name}}</p>
     <!-- author is available here -->
     {{#each project.entities}}
        <div class="audio">
            <div class="title-wave">
                <p class="title">{{this.title}}</p>
                <p class="author">by: {{../author.full_name}}</p>
                <!-- To access `author` you have to back out one conext level from the `project` each loop. -->
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<div id="rendered"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Might be because I'm in the context of backbone?

Comment: That shouldn't matter.

Comment: @SethMcClaine What version of Handlebars are you using?

Comment: "handlebars": "~1.3.0",

Comment: I've updated my example to use v1.3.0 and it still works. What is the definition of `self.template`? Are you using `Handlebars.compile` or something else?

Comment: `JST['public/scripts/templates/project.hbs']`

Comment: Using Grunt to compile everything